# Procedure not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi am making procedure that will deduct passes quantity from total quantity.

Right now I have taken static data means I haven't pass any value of argument with procedure.

But code is not deducting or updating the data of quantity.

Following is my code :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure1` ()
BEGIN
    update product_master set prod_qty  = (prod_qty - 10)
    where prod_id = 3;
END
```

Comment: Are you committing your changes after calling the procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Sir I have one query see answer's 2nd comment I have added, will you look it once ? I need help about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, it works for me.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE `new_procedure1`(IN pid INT(10))

    BEGIN
    UPDATE product_master SET prod_qty  = (prod_qty - 10) WHERE prod_id = pid;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and

```
CALL new_procedure1(1);
```

Comment: oh actually I miss to add my database name with table name, I have used other DB as default and right now I am working on other DB. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sir I want to put trigger before this method calls then How can I do that ? If trigger validation passes then only method calls otherwise display some error message. I want to check that suppose total qty is 40 and order qty is 5o then procedure should not be called. is it possible ?

Comment: post a new question to this.